# Spring Boot. how to secure some pages but not all the pages

Tags: spring-boot

We are creating a spring boot web application to send RSS data to a Ticker Sign (ticker).

The URLs that send RSS data to the ticker sign do not need to be secured with ldap or other credentials.

But we have one page we we update a custom message that we send to the Ticker sign.  We want to secure this page with the corporate ldap.

Is it possible to configure spring boot  to only require a login for one page and the rest of the pages can remain unsecured.

Comment: Read the docs and post again if you're having an issue: https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/#initial

Answer (score 0):

You can create a role with all permission to access and grant that access just in some methods using Spring security annotation http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html

```
<http use-expressions="true">
  <intercept-url pattern="/*"
      access="hasRole('admin')"/>
</http>
```

Then in your free access method

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('admin')")
public void create(Contact contact);
```

To use this it is very important that you name your URLs wisely i.e. if you want to assign admin role then make a URL look something like `/admin/v1/something-here`. It will make things readable and simple for you.